# Изменение ника новым участникам

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    var s = member.username
    let arr = ['-', '_', '+', '=', ')', '(', '?', '&', ':', '^', '*', '%', ';', '$', '№', '@', '"', '!', ':', ';', `'`, '/', '|', '?', '.', ',', '>', '<', '`', `~`]        
    while (arr.includes(s[0])) { // пока в массиве есть первый символ,
        s = s.substring(1) // удаляем его из строки через substring
    }
    if(!s) return; 
    member.setNickname(s) // dd            
});
```

Не работает, бот просто ничего не делает, а должен удалять символы из начала ника

Comment: А права у бота есть на смену ника?

Comment: есть, когда ивент меняю по сообщению всё работает